# Using angular 1.6.1 and angular-ui-router 0.3.2 make resolve issues

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

> This is my module:

```
> (function () {
>     'use strict';
> 
>     // CREATE module
>     angular
>         .module('home', []);
>     // Module's CONFIG
>     angular
>         .module('home')
>         .config(function ($stateProvider) {
>             console.log("angular.module('home').config()");
>             $stateProvider
>                 .state('search', {
>                     url: '/search',
>                     template: '<search books-list="$resolve.booksList"></search>',
>                     resolve: {
>                         booksList: function (dataService) {
>                             return dataService.get('app/data/books.json').then(function succsess(data) {
>                                 return data;
>                             }, function error(error) {
>                                 return error;
>                             });;
>                         }
>                     }
>                 });
>             /* Add New States Above */
>         }
> 
>         );
> 
> })();
```

> Here is my component:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

/* JAVASCRIPT */

/**
 * Search Object/function
 */

console.log("Search component load");

/** @ngInject **/
function searchController($state) {
    /***************** PRIVATE *******************/

    console.log("searchController load");
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.x = ctrl.booksList;

    /**
    * @name: .
    * @description: .
    **/

    /****************** PUBLIC *******************/
}
/* ANGULAR */
angular
    .module('home')
    .component('search', {
        templateUrl: 'app/home/components/search/search.component.html',
        controller: searchController,
        bindings: {
            booksList: '<'
        }
    });
```

})();

> I cant see the data that return from resolve function on my module
>   (equal to undefined)
>   Angular version 1.6.1 and ui router 0.3.2
>   Also try to inject the booksList to component controller but get
>   unknown provider error

Answer (score 1):

> Use this.$onInit to init my bookList like that:

```
this.$onInit = function _init() {
            ctrl.booksList = ctrl.books.data;

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to inject ui router

```
angular.module('yourmodule', [
    'ui.router'
  ]);
```

Comment: ok i did not see it here angular.module('home', []); or do you have other modules too

Comment: Update:see on ui the data by using $ctrl.booksList but on controller ctrl.booksList is undefined